# Finishing around brick veneer fireplace

Tags: brick, veneer

I am installing brick veneer around a fireplace and on the hearth, but am having trouble thinking of the best way to finish it along the floor.

There’s about 3/4 inch clearance between the floor and the bottom of the brick. I’ve tried cutting slices off the edge of other veneers and staggering them (as a standard brick pattern such that it would look like it’s going into the floor), but cutting them to 3/8 thickness without breaking has proved difficult. I’ve also thought about putting down a square dowel and/or shoe molding, as well as cutting the face of the existing front corner bricks in half so that I could place larger slices along the floor (the hearth is not mortared down yet). Painting/refinishing cut sides is not a huge deal, as matte acrylic paint seems to work well.

Any suggestions on how to give this a nice finish along the floor? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered leaving the gap? It's quite obvious from floor level, but only small children are likely to notice that. From above, there just appears to be a shadow line between the brick and wood, and it doesn't look bad _to me_.

Comment: That has been a consideration; in person it's almost like a floating effect and agree that it doesn't look terrible, but would otherwise be raw cement board there. I suppose it could be skim-coated, sanded, and painted, though!

Comment: A layer of mortar packed in there when you grout the bricks would probably help make it look more "made that way", like it was on a cement platform or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a piece of square trim that would fit under.  stain it to be the color of your floor or perhaps darker (or black).  It would cover the board but it would have a finished look.  I'd also try to make it thin enough so that it wouldn't stick out past the brick.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare plank from the floor then cut strips to fit and set it back from the edge of the brick by 1/4" - should look tidy.

Or put a chamfer on it and have the top flush... so many options.

Note: I would secure to the underside of the brick which should allow the floor to expand / contract as necessary.

Comment: @parabolox see edit...

Comment: Got it, thanks! Yeah, I think the biggest difficulty is maintaining the "rustic" characteristic. I'm thinking that if I went with wood trim, I may want to distress and/or whitewash it, instead of going with e.g. new stained quarter round.